# cc1 not in the PATH

Tags: kernel, configuration, path, gcc

I 'm trying to configure kernel via `make menuconfig` [Angstrom distribution] on BeagleBoard-xM, but I get these errors:

```
make: Warning: File `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.61/arch/arm/Makefile' has modification time 11647 s in the future
make[1]: Warning: File `scripts/Makefile.host' has modification time 11529 s in the future
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
```

As far I know, this is because cc1 is not in the PATH.

I have no Linux experience and I can't figure out what my next steps should be. Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after installing cpp: `opkg install cpp cpp-symlinks`.